# CMUcam5 Pixy on Raspberry 2

Tags: camera, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, robotics

I just got my Raspberry B and a new CMUcam 5 from Pixy.
I follow this tutorial:
[Hooking up Pixy to a Raspberry Pi](http://cmucam.org/projects/cmucam5/wiki/Hooking_up_Pixy_to_a_Raspberry_Pi)

However, once I plug-in the camera to the RB the servos keep on doing some noise like trying to move even when they are at their top.
The LED light keeps on flashing.
The worst part is that for some reason the mouse and keyboard are no longer connected until I click camera button.
Once I have the keyboard back and I try to run the hello_pixy script I get an error:

```
Hello Pixy:
libpixyusb: Version: 0.4
pixy_init(): USB ERROR: Target not found.
```

Am I missing something? Is something missing?
All suggestions are welcome

Thanks!

Comment: Well, doing some test I found that the issue was not about the software but the hardware. Seems like the servos need extra power that is beyond the simple USB cable. I added a powered-uss hub and now is working just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the power the servos need to move.
This was a hardware issue rather than a software one. 
Adding a simple powered-usb hub did the trick.